# Object with particle system doesn't appear but particles appear

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, particles

Well I was following Blender Guru's latest tutorial and when I went on to render this happened.[image: Rendered Image] 
Although it shows up fine in both viewport solid and rendered,[image: Viewport Render]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your *Particle System*, in the *Render* tab, check that the **Show Emitter** checkbox is on